# sort eigenvalues and associated eigenvectors after using numpy.linalg.eig in python

Tags: python, sorting, numpy

I'm using numpy.linalg.eig to obtain a list of eigenvalues and eigenvectors:

```
A = someMatrixArray
from numpy.linalg import eig as eigenValuesAndVectors

solution = eigenValuesAndVectors(A)

eigenValues = solution[0]
eigenVectors = solution[1]
```

I would like to sort my eigenvalues (e.g. from lowest to highest), in a way I know what is the associated eigenvector after the sorting.

I'm not finding any way of doing that with python functions. Is there any simple way or do I have to code my sort version?

Answer (score 207, accepted):

Use [numpy.argsort](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html#numpy.argsort). It returns the indices one would use to sort the array.

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.linalg as linalg

A = np.random.random((3,3))
eigenValues, eigenVectors = linalg.eig(A)

idx = eigenValues.argsort()[::-1]   
eigenValues = eigenValues[idx]
eigenVectors = eigenVectors[:,idx]
```

If the eigenvalues are complex, [the sort order is lexicographic](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html) (that is, complex numbers are sorted according to their real part first, with ties broken by their imaginary part).

Comment: Incidentally, it's more common to sort from largest to smallest eigenvalue.  just use: `idx = eigenValues.argsort()[::-1]`.

Comment: to get k largest eigenvalues
 k=2
 idx = eigenValues.argsort()[-k:][::-1]

Comment: For k=1 one can use `eigenVectors[:, eigenValues.argmax()]`

Comment: @CarlF. definitely a useful trick, but is it really more common? LAPACK (DSYEV) uses ascending order, I think that's a commonly used implementation (which Matlab and Python use)... Not that it really matters. upvote since it's useful trick anyway :-)

Comment: @MaxNoe: Per [the docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.eig.html), "The eigenvalues are not necessarily ordered."

Comment: Ah, i was using eigh: The eigenvalues in ascending order, each repeated according to its multiplicity.

Comment: @utapyngo Thanks; these comments answered my question; "the eigenvalues are not necessarily ordered," but "the eigenvalues ARE associated with their respective eigenvectors"

Answer (score 7):

Above answer by unutbu is very crisp and concise. But, here is another way we can do it which more general and can be used for lists as well.

```
eval, evec =  sp.eig(A)
ev_list = zip( eval, evec )
ev_list.sort(key=lambda tup:tup[0], reverse=False)
eval, evec = zip(*ev_list)
```

This tup[0] is the eigenvalue based on which the sort function will sort the list.

reverse = False is for increasing order.

Comment: AttributeError: 'zip' object has no attribute 'sort' =? could u help

Comment: I believe this is subtly wrong. When you zip the eigen values array and eigen vectors array together what happens is that each eigen value is paired with a *row* from the eigen vector array, but scipy returns eigen vectors as *columns* (i.e., evec[:,i] is the i-th eigen vector. ) In short the correct approach would be `zip(eval, evec.T)`.

Answer (score 6):

The ubuntu's piece of code doesn't work on my Python 3.6.5. It leads run-time errors. So, I refactored his/her code to this one which works ok on my test cases:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import linalg as npla
#
def eigen(A):
    eigenValues, eigenVectors = npla.eig(A)
    idx = np.argsort(eigenValues)
    eigenValues = eigenValues[idx]
    eigenVectors = eigenVectors[:,idx]
    return (eigenValues, eigenVectors)
```

Comment: I just wanted to emphasize the importance of eigenVectors[:,idx] since the numpy.linalg.eig documentation says  'The normalized (unit “length”) eigenvectors, such that the column eigenvectors[:,i] is the eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue eigenvalues[i].'