# python numpy sort eigenvalues

Tags: python, numpy

I am using linalg.eig(A) to get the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a matrix. Is there an easy way to sort these eigenvalues (and associated vectors) in order?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8092920/sort-eigenvalues-and-associated-eigenvectors-after-using-numpy-linalg-eig-in-pyt

Comment: If the matrix is real and symmetric (or complex and Hermitian), `linalg.eigh()` returns the real eigenvalues in ascending order. https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.eigh.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to use the NumPy `sort()` and `argsort()` functions. `argsort()` returns the permutation of indices needed to sort an array, so if you want to sort by eigenvalue magnitude (the standard sort for NumPy arrays seems to be smallest-to-largest), you can do:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.asarray([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
eig_vals, eig_vecs = np.linalg.eig(A)

eig_vals_sorted = np.sort(eig_vals)
eig_vecs_sorted = eig_vecs[:, eig_vals.argsort()]


# Alternatively, to avoid making new arrays
# do this:

sort_perm = eig_vals.argsort()

eig_vals.sort()     # <-- This sorts the list in place.
eig_vecs = eig_vecs[:, sort_perm]
```

Comment: In your second example, no need to call sort() on eig_vals again, you already have sort_perm. i.e. eig_vals = eig_vals[sort_perm]

Comment: Good point! I wasn't sure whether using the slice notation `[]` made an extra copy of the list. My thinking was that at least one of them can be done in place, and I didn't know if `a = a[sort_perm]` is as efficient as `a.sort()`.

Comment: The eig_vecs are column vectors, so it should be eig_vecs[:, eig_vals.argsort()], right?

Comment: @denvar Thanks -- I fixed the typo.

Answer (score -3):

`np.linalg.eig` will often return complex values. You may want to consider using `np.sort_complex(eig_vals)`.

Comment: It would be preferable to ensure the matrix is symmetric and use `linalg.eigh`