# How to diagonalize a large symmetric matrix in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy, eigenvector

I have a large symmetric matrix in python which I want to diagonalize. The matrix I am using has a size of ~35000x35000, and I am using numpy's memmap to store the matrix (dtype=float64).

However, whenever I am using the `numpy.linalg.eigh` routine to diagonalize the matrix. Whenever I am looking at the results, it seems that the eigenvalues are ridiculously low and the eigenvectors are coming out to be zeros.

There seems to be a problem with the subroutine, since I have been using same code for 8800x8800 matrix and I am getting good reasonable results.

P.S. I will have to use this to diagonalize even larger matrices, so please suggest some good subroutine.

List of hardware/software:

- CPU: Intel Xeon Silver 4110 (32 core)
- RAM: 93 GB
- Python: Anaconda 2020.02 (Python 3.7.6)
- Available Hard Drive space: ~13 TB

P.P.S.:Please do not suggest me [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33037616/large-matrix-diagonalization-python), as this idea has already been tested and it failed miserably.

Comment: The chances that it is the eigh's fault and not yours is approximately 0.  Feel free to prove me wrong with some actual code though.

Comment: @FiddleStix The reason I claim this is a problem with eigh routine is simply because it works with 8800 dimensional matrix properly. You can trust me on this, since I used the exact same code. It is an extremely large code, used for statistical analysis of molecular dynamics trajectory, and will be difficult to explain both in terms of algorithm and chemistry.

Comment: @FiddleStix This error is already known, it is given in github. I just want a bypass method to it.
https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/13956

Comment: @MitradipDas Did you take a look at SymPy or Pytorch methods to diagonalize a symmetric matrix? I do not have enough compute power to check if they fail after a certain threshold, but I am not finding any related issue.

Comment: I don mean to offend you - of course you are free to ask for it, and anyone is free to contribute - but these are the specs for a consulting job. You may get lucky and have a nice answer here, and we all may be lucky if this trigger actions that will have the bug fixed. There is no problem with posting that - but it is nicer if you know what you are asking for people to do for you.

Comment: it seems that NumPy is starting to roll out build with 64-bit int indices BLAS, so if you are after the simplest solution, I think waiting for NumPy to address it may just be enough. Otherwise you could look into doing the computation in Julia (where this issue seems to be alreay being taken care of) and then just load the result in Python.

Comment: Is it a sparse or a dense matrix? For sparse matrices there are packages available, for dense matrices this would be really hard to implement. eg. https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/470282?

Comment: Have you tried [scipy.linalg.eigh()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.eigh.html) ?

Comment: @max9111 The matrix is very dense, so sparse matrix packages won't work good for me.

Comment: @igrinis I did try scipy.linalg.eigh(). The problem happening is as follows. I have some 300 matrices to diagonalize. I am using scipy.linalg.eigh(matrix,b=None,turbo=True,check_finite=False) and for first matrix it is taking some 15 minutes, which is expected. Second matrix onwards it is taking up 16 hours to diagonalize each matrix, and that's why I am a bit fed up with it.

Comment: @igrinis I am somehow having this gut feeling that scipy is not clearing something after diagonalization. If so, can you please let me know if I need to clear any reminiscent memory in order to have the second and later matrices take ~15 minutes each? If so, please let me know.

Comment: It sounds like the first run uses all the memory, and subsequent runs have to use swap. Try to force garbage collection. Also, make sure you have Intel MKL version and not regular openBLAS. And finally, try replacing `b=np.eye(len(matrix), dtype = matrix.dtype)` , it should also boost performance.

Comment: At the least, go through carefully using `del` on all your variables in the loop... make sure the first matrix is fully gone before starting to load the second one.

If it's something internal in scipy, that may be harder to fix; at the worst, you might have to put each matrix diagonalisation in a separate job (or in a separate invocation of Python).